# LPC 1769 Ethernet MAC for internet connection

Tags: tcp, ethernet, mcu

I am trying to use LPC 1769 for an IOT application. I wanted to incorporate an MQTT client in the MCU code. But understood MQTT client need TCP/IP stack. On reading datasheet I understood LPC 1769 support ethernet MAC only. I have two queries as below

- Since TCP/IP stack isn't built on the MCU, can't the MCU connect to internet using just ethernet MAC?
- What is the use of stand alone ethernet MAC option on MCU if not for internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

> can't the MCU connect to internet using just ethernet MAC?

No. The Internet talks TCP/IP, it doesn't talk Ethernet, even if it might use it for underlying transport extensively.

You'll require a TCP/IP stack to connect to the IP world. Check out lwIP and the like.